# UITableView broke after upgrading to swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode8

After converting to Swift 3 and Xcode 8 both the UITableViews in my app don't produce the action when clicking on the cells.
It still retrieves data from the datasource but won't produce any alerts or segues.

Anyone have an idea why this might be?

I went back through converted back to swift 2 and went back to Xcode 7.
However, it still doesn't work.

*Delegate and Datasource set in storyboard

```
import UIKit


protocol TravelFeedViewControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidStartLoading(controller: TravelFeedViewController)
    func controllerDidStopLoading(controller: TravelFeedViewController)
}

class TravelFeedViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    enum FeedMode: String {
        case Global
        case Personal
    }

    var feedMode: FeedMode!                                 // Setting the mode to global/personal will fetch the corresponding array
    var delegate: TravelFeedViewControllerDelegate?
    var tableDataSource = [String]()                //[Post]()
    let cellIdentifier = "FeedCell"

    // MARK: - View Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        assert(feedMode != nil, "Set feedMode before presenting controller")

        self.loadFeed()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Posts

    /**
     Requests posts
     */
    func loadFeed() {
        self.delegate?.controllerDidStartLoading(self)

        if self.feedMode == .Global {
            self.tableDataSource = ["Global","Global","Global","Global","Global","Global","Global"]
//            User.getGlobalPosts { (syttrs: Array<Post>?) -> Void in
//                if let syttrsArray = syttrs {
//                    self.tableDataSource = syttrsArray
//                    self.tableView.reloadData()
//                }
//                self.delegate?.controllerDidStopLoading(self)
//            }

            // Load parents
        } else if self.feedMode == .Personal {
            self.tableDataSource = ["Personal"]
//            User.getFriendsPosts({ (parents: Array<Post>?) -> Void in
//                if let parentArray = parents {
//                    self.tableDataSource = parentArray
//                    self.tableView.reloadData()
//                }
//                self.delegate?.controllerDidStopLoading(self)
//            })
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.delegate?.controllerDidStopLoading(self)
    }
}

extension TravelFeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90.0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return  1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let post = self.tableDataSource[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        if let profileVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PostDetailVC") as? PostDetailViewController {
            profileVC.post = post
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableDataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        if let castedCell = cell as? FeedTableViewCell {
            let post = self.tableDataSource[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            castedCell.postLabel.text = post
            castedCell.imageContainer.layer.cornerRadius = castedCell.imageContainer.frame.size.width / 2.0
            castedCell.imageContainer.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.QIconGray
            castedCell.personImageView.image = nil
            castedCell.personImageView.image = UIImage(named: "silhouette") // = UIImage(data: result!)
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Most of the table view data source and delegate methods are still Swift 2 code. Look into the documentation for the proper syntax.

Comment: Dude whats up? people are investing their time to help you. At least answer

Comment: Apologizes I hadn't gotten home yet. I shall look it over now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `tableView` Code to Swift 3:

```
extension TravelFeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 90.0
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return  1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let post = self.tableDataSource[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        if let profileVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PostDetailVC") as? PostDetailViewController {
            profileVC.post = post
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableDataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        if let castedCell = cell as? FeedTableViewCell {
            let post = self.tableDataSource[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            castedCell.postLabel.text = post
            castedCell.imageContainer.layer.cornerRadius = castedCell.imageContainer.frame.size.width / 2.0
            castedCell.imageContainer.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.QIconGray
            castedCell.personImageView.image = nil
            castedCell.personImageView.image = UIImage(named: "silhouette") // = UIImage(data: result!)
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: I was actually trying to convert it back to Swift 2 syntax but you did help me realize that I didn't finish the job and left it as 'didSelectAtRow indexPath:...' instead of 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:...'.

I feel stupid for asking now but the help was much appreciated!

Comment: well bro. always glad to help. let me know if you need further assistance

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct syntax of **Swift 3**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

}
```

;)